# Configuration Apple's HTTP Live Streaming with Apache + PHP on MAC machine

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video-streaming

I tried Live video and VOD streaming on iPhone, for that i have configured HTTP Live server with Apache + PHP on Mac machine. Also FFMPEG command line tool on my MAC system.

First i tried Video On Demand (VOD) with below steps,

1. I have encoded input video (.mp4) using FFMPEG tool to MPEF2 (.ts)
2. Using mediastreamsegmenter command line tool, to create index file (.m3u8) and segmentation

When i do the above step 2, it is not working, can you suggest me which i followed the steps are correct or correct me if i anything wrong.

Second, Live video stream

Recording video on iPhone camera and i receiving CFsampebufferref on delegate method. How should i send the above mentioned buffer (iphone) to server (Apache + PHP) in which format and how should i read in server and best communication method, whether is Socket or ftp or some other methods?

Thanks in advance,

Sri

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more specific with the error? Does not load the video? Crashes? With this little info could be a programatic problem, encoding one or even apache.

Start by using mediastreamvalidator in your MAC and check if the video part is correct. If everything is fine, try accessing the m3u8 file with your browser. If it is showing then the problem should be in the app itself.